# Reload Content of UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a problem with refreshing the content of a `UITableView`. I'm trying to display a list of members in a `UITableView`. Above this list I have some kind of dropdown-menu for a group selection. So, if I change the group, selected in the dropdown-menu, I want to change the content of the UITableView underneath it. It's actually not working correctly. 
The first time I load the `ViewController` that contains the `UITableView`, it shows the correct list of members in the default group. Now, when I change the group, it should display my new list of members, but it doesn't. It seems that the `UITableView` would not even reload its table content.
Here is my code for the `TableViewController`:

MemberTableViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.members = [NSMutableArray new];
  self.selectedRows = [NSMutableArray new];
  self.groupManager = [GroupManager new];

  int *number;
  if (nil != [self gruppeId]) {
      number = [[self gruppeId] intValue]; // Here will be the id of the new selected group
  } else {
    number = 4010292; // This is just for testing. It's the id of my default group
  }

  for (Group *group in [self.groupManager findGroupWithID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:number]]) {

    for (Member *member in group.member) {
        [self.members addObject:member];
    }
  }

  NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
  [self.gruppenMitglieder sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
  [self.tableView setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return  [[self members] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    GreenTexturedCell *cell = nil;
    Member *member = [self members][indexPath.row];
    NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GreenTexturedCell" owner:nil    options:nil];

    for (UIView *view in views) {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            cell = (GreenTexturedCell*)view;
        }
    }


    cell.textLabel.text = member.name;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"JandaCloserToFree" size:14.0];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    return cell;
}
```

Now I have another `ViewController` the `MemberListViewController`, it contains the `MemberTableViewController` (I know, the naming is not the best...). The `MemberListViewController` implements a protocol of the `GroupSelectionTableViewController`. Its delegate function will be called when the selected group changes. Here is the code for the `MemberListViewController`:
MemberListViewController.h

```
@interface MemberListViewController : UIViewController <GroupSelectionDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *groupSelection;
@property (nonatomic, strong) GroupSelectionTableViewController *groupTableView;
- (IBAction)groupSelectionPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

MemberListViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setGroupTableView:[GroupSelectionTableViewController new]];
    [[self groupTableView] setDelegate:self];
}

- (IBAction)gruppeAuswahlPressed:(id)sender {

    if ([self groupListShown]) {
        [[[self groupTableView] view] removeFromSuperview];
        [self setGroupListShown:NO];
    } else {
        [self.view addSubview:[[self groupTableView] view]];
        [self setGroupListShown:YES];
    }
}

- (void) groupSelectionController:(GroupSelectionTableViewController *)groupSelection DidSelectGroupWithId:(NSString *) groupId {
    [[self groupSelection] setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[[self groupTableView] view] removeFromSuperview];
    [self setGroupListShown:NO];
    MemberTableViewController *memberTableView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"memberTable"];
    [memberTableView setGroupId:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4017411]]; // Id for testing
    [memberTableView refreshControl];
```

}

Now, if I change the group selection, the `-groupSelectionController:DidSelectGroupWithId:` Method is called and with `[memberTableView refreshControl]` I'm able to get into the `viewDidLoad` Method of the `MemberTableViewController` again and set the groupId to my testing id. Now i want the TableView to reload its content to get the members of the selected group. With the statement `[self.tableView reloadData]` I'm getting into the `tableView:NumberOfRowsInSection:` Method but not into the tableView:CellForRowAtIndexPath: Method and the TableView Content is not redrawn.

What am I doing wrong ?
This problem is driving me nuts, so I hope there's someone to help me out.
Thanks

Comment: Have you logged what numberOfRowsInSection is returning? Usually, if that method is called but not cellForRowAtIndexPath, it's because the number of rows is 0.

Comment: Yes I did. The first time it returns 12 an when I changed the group it returns 6 which is the correct number of members in the selected group.

Comment: I'm a little lost in which table is not redrawing. Is is memberTableView? If so, change [memberTableView refreshControl] to [memberTableView reloadData] and see if that helps.

Comment: My guess is that with `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` you are creating a new instance of MemberTableViewController, which isn't the one you are showing on screen. Hence, you won't see the changes which should be shown by calling reloadData

Comment: You say you're not getting into cellFroRowAtIndexPath, did you verify that by logging?

Comment: First, yes you're right, the memberTableView is not reddrawing. I'll now try to use reloadData instead of refreshControl. And yes i verified it by logging. I'm getting into the numberOfRowsInSection but not in the cellForRowAtIndexPath. That's what is confusing me. I thought reloadData would call numbersOfRowsInSection and i the number is >0 it will call cellForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: @simpleBob Ok that sounds possible. I'm trying to figure it out. Anyway, is there a way do "re-instantiate" an existing ViewController ?

Comment: @matthisb You will have to create an IBOutlet for the UITableView and access it per code. With the Storyboard you can only get the equivalent to what would be a class, but you can not get existing instances.

Comment: @simpleBob OK you're right, the MemberTableViewController I instantiated with Identifier is not showing on the screen. Of course not... So, now I'm facing the problem to access the MemberTableViewController form the MemberListViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` you are creating a new instance of `MemberTableViewController`, which isn't the one you are showing on screen. Hence, you won't see the changes which should be shown by calling reloadData.

To be able to reload the table data, you can add a link to the table at your MemberListViewController. Change the code of the .h to:

```
#import "MemberTableViewController.h"
@interface MemberListViewController : UIViewController <GroupSelectionDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet MemberTableViewController *memberTableView;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *groupSelection;
@property (nonatomic, strong) GroupSelectionTableViewController *groupTableView;
- (IBAction)groupSelectionPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

and then, in the .m, you can call [memberTableView reloadData];

Do not forget to set `memberTableView` as "new referencing outlet" within the storyboard file.

Comment: Greeeat! That worked for me. Thank you. My tableView is now refreshen correctly